# How to update inputTextarea in richfaces

Tags: java, html, richfaces

I have bean "RichFacesTreeNodeBean" with property "newItemInfo", and I call modal panel with inputTextArea, which must contain actual value of that property, but it contains the first value of property all the time. Here is the part of index.xhtml:

```
<rich:popupPanel id="editPanel">
    <h:form>
        <h:inputTextarea value="#{richFacesTreeNodeBean.newItemInfo}" />
        <!-- some buttons -->
    </h:form>
</rich:popupPanel>
```

And RichFacesTreeNodeBean.java:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class RichFacesTreeNodeBean {
     private String newItemInfo;

public String getNewItemInfo() {
    return newItemInfo;
}
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<h:form>
    <a4j:outputPanel layout="block" ajaxRendered="true"> 
         <h:inputTextarea value="#{richFacesTreeNodeBean.newItemInfo}" />
    </a4j:outputPanel>
</h:form>
```

It works.